# Fetch data from the past 5 days PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to return data only from the last five days in PostgreSQL using the following query

```
SELECT id, id, text, author, updated_at 
FROM public.table 
WHERE date_trunc('day', updated_at) <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '5 days';
```

**Example data in updated_at field: 2022-03-10 16:46:17.42916**

However, the above query returns all the results in the table instead of the required ones. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here (I'm quite new to PSQL)

The schema of my table is as follows

```
"id"            "integer"
"updated_at"    "timestamp without time zone"
"tweet_id"      "character varying"
"text"          "character varying"
"author"        "character varying"
"created_at"    "character varying"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return data from the *last* 5 days then your inequality needs to be flipped around:

```sql
SELECT id, id, text, author, updated_at
FROM public.table
WHERE updated_at >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '5 days';
```

Comment: That gives me 0 rows for some reason. Even though the data does exist for the last 5 days

Comment: Without seeing your data I can't comment further, but the logic in my answer is what you want to be using here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The `DATE_TRUNC` on left side is useless (in this case). More, it can block index on column `updated_at` (but this is issue of original query, not yours). The predicate should to look like `updated_at >= CURRENT_DATE - interval '5days'` or `updated_at >= date_trunc(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'day') - interval '5days'`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - it should to work, because you use `CURRENT_DATE`, not `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. The right side is truncated already (this is not Oracle's SYSDATE where it can be necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Can try this one:

```
SELECT
    id,
    id,
    text,
    author,
    updated_at 
FROM
    PUBLIC.table 
WHERE
audit_date::DATE BETWEEN NOW()::DATE-'5 DAYS'::INTERVAL AND NOW()::DATE
```